# How to create SSL Certificate for Multipeer Connectivity in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios7, multipeer-connectivity

Apple introduce the Multipeer Connectivity framework in iOS7 to communicate with different devices. This framework also provide the functionality of Secure/Authenticated communication between devices by using SSL certificate.

I have tried the http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html but it does not work for me.

I want to implement the Secure/Authenticated communication but not able to understand how to obtain the SSL certificate for test environment.
Can any one help me by providing the step of creating the SSL certificate that can be used in multipeer to transfer the Secure/Authenticated data.

Is there any need to purchase any kind of certificate to implement this functionality?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?